# Get value of HTML select option using its index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

HTML for select and options:

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

I want the value of the option at index 1, something along the lines of

```
$('.dropdown[1]').value
// should return 'two'
```

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Comment: Yes I looked there and couldn't find the right methods. I also searched this site many times. I could have written a list of everything I'd tried but one example sufficed. What do you want me to say.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$('.dropdown option').eq(1).val()
```

[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) will start with 0 as it is an index

Get the currently selected value with

```
$('.dropdown option:selected').val()
```

use `text()` instead of `val()` to retrieve the text content

Comment: Wow fast. Thanks guys I've been trying to do this for over an hour. Will mark this as answer when I can.

Answer (score 11):

To get the text:

```
var list = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var value = list.options[1].text;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get the value:

```
$('select.dropdown option').eq(1).val();
```

An this to get the text:

```
$('select.dropdown option').eq(1).text();
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dkQYz/)**