# How to get <option> from <select> by its index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having here a `<select>` that looks like this:

```
<select id="stdin-select" class="io-byte-box" size="10">
    <option>0x5232</option>
    <option>0xFD13</option>
    <option>0x13E7</option>
    <option>0x1234</option>
    <option>0xFFFF</option>
</select>
```

and I am trying to access the values by its *index* like this:

```
var stdinValue = $('.stdin-select.dropdown option').eq(0).text();
```

and this

```
var stdinValue = $('.stdin-select option').eq(0).text();
```

like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520594/get-value-of-html-select-option-using-its-index-with-jquery) but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.` is for classes. `#` is for IDs.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Right. Works. Didn't know that.. dayum .. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `class` (.) to `id` ('#')

```
var stdinValue = $('#stdin-select option').eq(0).text();
```

In your example there is not element with class `stdin-select`, instead there is element with if `stdin-select`

Comment: *argh* ... yes that works.. thank you. Didn't know the difference! Thanks ^^